# How to remove the link to the draft pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the title of the page with no links to the draft pages.
this is my code

```
<?php
wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li'    => '',
    'child_of'    => '4721',
    'post_status'  => 'publish,draft' 
) );
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object :

```
$child_pages_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    //'post_parent'    => '4721',
    'post_status'    => array('publish', 'draft')
));
if($child_pages_query->have_posts()){
    while($child_pages_query->have_posts()){
        $child_pages_query->the_post();
        if('publish'==get_post_status(get_the_ID())){
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
        }else{
            echo '<li>'.get_the_title().'</li>';
        }
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```